# Impossible to get the URL of a tab with chrome extension (manifest v3)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I've been struggling for a long time with Chrome Extensions. How do I get the URL of the tab from `background.js` (my service worker) ?

It seems like a very easy thing to do but........

```json
// manifest.json
{
  "name": "Getting Started Example",
  "description": "Build an Extension!",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "scripting"],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

```js
// background.js
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(activeInfo => {
  chrome.tabs.get(activeInfo.tabId, (tab) => {
    // tab.url is undefined, it should not.
  });
});
```

it doesn't work. why ?

Comment: You need the `tabs` permission. See [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#manifest).

Comment: Also note that `actuveTab` permission is for a completely different use case: it gives temporary access to the currently active tab **when the user invokes the extension** - for example by clicking its action.

Comment: Your code works for me. Please clarify what behavior you want.

Comment: It's already been answered by the comment above actually, subject closed, thank you